# Pipe in ZSH is stripping colors from Git log output

Tags: linux, git, zsh

I'm trying to utilize GRB's git helpers (https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/.githelpers) for pretty printing my git log.

The `git log --graph --pretty="tformat:${LOG_FORMAT}"` command from line #62 works just fine; printing with colors in iTerm. But as soon as it's piped to `pretty_git_format` there are no colors displayed.

This has been working for several years until just a few weeks ago. Was there a change in zsh that I now need to configure differently?

I'm using iTerm2 and zsh version zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0).

Comment: Did you check if your pager leaves the raw output (to preserve colors)? `git config --global core.pager 'less -R'`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64932/7490

Comment: That's not it. Even if I just `git log --graph --pretty="tformat:${LOG_FORMAT}" | cat` it prints without color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior for git is to produce color if the output is being printed to a terminal (directly or through a git-spawned pager). When your output goes somewhere else, like a pipe, git turns off colors.

You can set the `color.ui` option to `always` on the command line like this: `git -c color.ui=always log --graph --pretty="tformat:${LOG_FORMAT}"` (and yes, that's where the `-c` option goes).  If you want to do this frequently, it can be done with a shell alias in `.gitconfig`.

While you *can* set this in your `.gitconfig` as well, you probably don't want to.  Most external programs assume color is turned off, and you can break other parts of git, as well as tools like editor integrations, if you set this in `.gitconfig`.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I wonder why this is now needed, when in the past it wasn't.

Comment: @MatthewBoston - I'm having this same issue. Adding `-c color.ui=always` works as you say, but seems to also affect the column formatting from `pretty_git_format`.  Are you finding that too?

Answer (score 1):

This started happening to me today, after updating to OSX High Sierra and updating my homebrew packages.

I suspect it is something to do with the latest Git version (2.15.0), as those [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.15.0.txt) mention changing how the `git log` colors work:

```
Fixes since v2.14
-----------------

 * "%C(color name)" in the pretty print format always produced ANSI
   color escape codes, which was an early design mistake.  They now
   honor the configuration (e.g. "color.ui = never") and also tty-ness
   of the output medium.
```

So I think Brian's solution is probably the best one, but I do note that it does seem to affect the column formatting of `pretty_git_format`, which I mentioned in a comment above.